# Comparing speeds between sqlalchemy ORM and raw sql queries in a flask API

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

There is a function for a POST route in a flask API that we use to validate some data. After adding a new column property to one of the referenced models in the function, the API response times got a lot slower. So I thought maybe using a raw sql query that only queries the necessary columns would make it faster. However, when I check the response times the new query is significantly slower than the previous query that utilizes sqlalchemy. Why would that be the case, and is there a way to perform queries using sqlalchemy that don't create specific column properties or select specific columns/column properties? Here is the function, the two different queries have commented titles:

```
def validate_data(payload):
    payload_client_id = payload.get('client_id', None)
    payload_brief_id = payload.get('brief_id', None)
    payload_plan_id = payload.get('plan_id', None)
    payload_buy_id = payload.get('buy_id', None)

    errors = {}
    # Using SQLAlchemy
    if payload_buy_id is not None:
        buy_record = BuyModel.query.filter_by(id=payload_buy_id).one()
        print('waldo brief_id?', buy_record.brief_id)
        if payload_plan_id != buy_record.plan_id:
            errors['plan_id'] = f'payload.plan_id {payload_plan_id} != buy.plan_id {buy_record.plan_id}'
        if payload_brief_id != buy_record.brief_id:
            errors['brief_id'] = f'payload.brief_id {payload_brief_id} != buy.brief_id {buy_record.brief_id}'
        if payload_client_id != buy_record.client_id:
            errors['client_id'] = f'payload.client_id {payload_client_id} != buy.client_id {buy_record.client_id}'

    # Using raw SQL
    if payload_buy_id is not None:
        print('here')
        session = create_pg_session()
        sql = text(
        "SELECT buy.id, buy.plan_id, "
        "plan.brief_id AS brief_id, "
        "brief.client_id AS client_id "
        "FROM buy "
        "JOIN plan ON buy.plan_id = plan.id "
        "JOIN brief ON plan.brief_id = brief.id "
        "WHERE buy.id = :id"
        )
        result = session.execute(sql, {'id': payload_buy_id})
        buy_record = result.fetchone()
        print('buy record', buy_record)
        if buy_record is None:
            errors['buy_id'] = f'Buy record with id {payload_buy_id} not found'
        else:
            if payload_plan_id != buy_record.plan_id:
                errors['plan_id'] = f'payload.plan_id {payload_plan_id} != buy.plan_id {buy_record.plan_id}'
            if payload_brief_id != buy_record.brief_id:
                errors['brief_id'] = f'payload.brief_id {payload_brief_id} != buy.brief_id {buy_record.brief_id}'
            if payload_client_id != buy_record.client_id:
                errors['client_id'] = f'payload.client_id {payload_client_id} != buy.client_id {buy_record.client_id}'
```

I have tried writing raw sql queries to increase API response times, but it ended up making them even slower. My main question is why using the sqlalchemy orm is faster in this case, and if there is a way to incorporate my logic from the raw sql query into an orm query that does not add a particular column property?

Comment: What is `create_pg_session`?  Is that just creating a cursor?  You certainly do not want to open a new connection for each query.  That query should run just about as fast as a query can run.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for the different SQL statements? (In plain text, as an update to your question). The ddl for tables and indexes involved would be helpful as well